# Is there a way to make PhpStorm to download a file automatically every day at a particular time?

Tags: download, scheduled-tasks, phpstorm

Is there a way to make PhpStorm to download a file automatically every day at a particular time ?

Comment: Why exactly phpstorm should do it? Why not cron?

Comment: There is no such functionality in PhpStorm and extremely unlikely to ever be -- this is not a function of IDE to do such stuff (download some random file on regular basis). You should use either your OS's task scheduler for such stuff or write custom plugin if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a feature of PHPSTORM

please look into a cron job